# Qualify clause in Oracle

Tags: oracle11g, teradata

I'm working in Teradata to Oracle migration project. How can i modify the below query which is using QUALIFY in Teradata.

//QUERY 1

```
   SELECT S.ID  as Id,
          S.MP_CD as Code,
          S.GM_CD  as GmCode,
          S.GM_MSR_NBR as Mea_Year, 
          S.STTS_CD as YearCode,
          S.TRMNTN_DTM as TerminationDate 
     FROM PD.RVY S, LOAD_LOG TLL 
    WHERE S.UPDTD_LOAD = TLL.LOG_KEY AND TLL.BLSH_CD = 'Y' AND S.STTS_CD IN ( 'C', 'P' ) 
  QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY S.GM_CD ,S.MP_CD ,S.GM_MSR_NBR,S.STTS_CD 
                              ORDER BY S.SO_DTM DESC 
                              ) = 1;
```

//Query 2

```
  SELECT SP.ID,
         SP.SO_DTM,
         SP.TAX_ID,
         SP.USER_ID,
         SP.FRST_NM,
         SP.LAST_NM,
         SP.PHONE_NBR,
         QSRP.TAX_ID,
         QSRP.ROW_ID,
         MAX(SP.SO_DTM) OVER (PARTITION BY SP.ID, SP.TAX_ID) MAX_SO_DTM       
    FROM VOPR_RMSY SP,VOPR_RMSY_SPNS QSRP
    WHERE  SP.ID =:URVYID AND QSRP.TAX_ID =:RPAXID 
          AND SP.ID = QSRP.ID AND SP.TAX_ID = QSRP.TAX_ID AND SP.SO_DTM = QSRP.SO_DTM 
    QUALIFY (SP.SO_DTM=MAX_SO_DTM AND QSRP.SO_DTM = MAX_SO_DTM) 
    GROUP BY SP.ID,SP.SO_DTM,SP.TAX_ID,SP.USER_ID,SP.FRST_NM,SP.LAST_NM,SP.PHONE_NBR,
            QSRP.TAX_ID,QSRP.ROW_ID;
```

For this tried with HAVING instead of qualify but got an Error:

> ORA-00904: "MAX_SO_DTM": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Seems like alias used for MAX is not working here....

Any of your help is really appreciated!

EDITED:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (         
 SP.ID,
     SP.SO_DTM,
     SP.TAX_ID,
     SP.USER_ID,
     SP.FRST_NM,
     SP.LAST_NM,
     SP.PHONE_NBR,
     QSRP.TAX_ID,
     QSRP.ROW_ID,
     MAX(SP.SO_DTM) OVER (PARTITION BY SP.ID, SP.TAX_ID) AS MAX_SO_DTM       
FROM VOPR_RMSY SP,VOPR_RMSY_SPNS QSRP 
WHERE  SP.ID =:URVYID AND QSRP.TAX_ID =:RPAXID AND SP.ID = QSRP.ID AND SP.TAX_ID =  
       QSRP.TAX_ID AND SP.SO_DTM = QSRP.SO_DTM 
GROUP BY SP.ID,SP.SO_DTM,SP.TAX_ID,SP.USER_ID,SP.FRST_NM,SP.LAST_NM,SP.PHONE_NBR,
        QSRP.TAX_ID,QSRP.ROW_ID;
 )dt WHERE (SP.SO_DTM=MAX_SO_DTM AND QSRP.SO_DTM = MAX_SO_DTM)
```

i know that i have to use alias dt for outer WHERE instead of SP and QSRP but here MAX_SO_DTM is compared with SO_DTM from two different tables. is there any other way to modify this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both QUALIFY and reusing an alias is Teradata specific.

Your try with HAVING is failing, because this is the logical sequence of processing a query:

```
FROM
WHERE
GROUP BY
HAVING
OLAP-function
QUALIFY -- Teradata specific
SAMPLE or EXPAND ON  -- both are Teradata specific
ORDER
```

To resolve this you have to use a Derived Table/Inline View and move the QUALIFY condition into the outer WHERE.

```
SELECT *
FROM
 (
   SELECT S.ID  as Id,
          S.MP_CD as Code,
          S.GM_CD  as GmCode,
          S.GM_MSR_NBR as Mea_Year, 
          S.STTS_CD as YearCode,
          S.TRMNTN_DTM as TerminationDate,
          ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY S.GM_CD ,S.MP_CD ,S.GM_MSR_NBR,S.STTS_CD 
                          ORDER BY S.SO_DTM DESC) AS rn 
     FROM PD.RVY S, LOAD_LOG TLL 
    WHERE S.UPDTD_LOAD = TLL.LOG_KEY AND TLL.BLSH_CD = 'Y' AND S.STTS_CD IN ( 'C', 'P' ) 
  ) dt
WHERE rn = 1;
```

The same technique must be used when you want to reuse an alias.

EDIT:
The 2nd query can be rewritten as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
 (        
   SELECT 
        SP.ID,
        SP.SO_DTM,
        SP.TAX_ID,
        SP.USER_ID,
        SP.FRST_NM,
        SP.LAST_NM,
        SP.PHONE_NBR,
        QSRP.TAX_ID,
        QSRP.ROW_ID,
        MAX(SP.SO_DTM) OVER (PARTITION BY SP.ID, SP.TAX_ID) AS MAX_SO_DTM       
   FROM VOPR_RMSY SP,VOPR_RMSY_SPNS QSRP 
   WHERE SP.ID =:URVYID 
     AND QSRP.TAX_ID =:RPAXID 
     AND SP.ID = QSRP.ID 
     AND SP.TAX_ID =  QSRP.TAX_ID 
     AND SP.SO_DTM = QSRP.SO_DTM
   GROUP BY SP.ID,SP.SO_DTM,SP.TAX_ID,SP.USER_ID,SP.FRST_NM,SP.LAST_NM,SP.PHONE_NBR,
           QSRP.TAX_ID,QSRP.ROW_ID
 )dt
WHERE SO_DTM=MAX_SO_DTM
```

You don't need to do both comparisons *(SP.SO_DTM=MAX_SO_DTM AND QSRP.SO_DTM = MAX_SO_DTM)*, because they the 2nd is redundant as the tables are joined on *SP.SO_DTM = QSRP.SO_DTM*.

Otherwise you had to add QSRP.SO_DTM to the Derived Table using a different alias (e.g. QSRP_SO_DTM). In the outer level there's no more SP/QSRP but only dt, so it would be:

```
WHERE (SO_DTM=MAX_SO_DTM AND QSRP_SO_DTM = MAX_SO_DTM)
```

Comment: Hi dhoeth, i tried the second query with the same technique. i got an error like ORA-00904: "QSRP"."SO_DTM": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier".Query : SELECT * FROM( SELECT column names,MAX(SP.SO_DTM) OVER (PARTITION BY SP.ID, SP.TAX_ID) AS MAX_SO_DTM FROM VOPR_RMSY SP,VOPR_RMSY_SPNS QSRP WHERE  clause GROUP BY clause)t1 WHERE SP.SO_DTM=MAX_SO_DTM AND QSRP.SO_DTM = MAX_SO_DTM. Is there any problem in using table alias name in outer where clause?

Comment: In the outer query there's no more SP/QSRP, so it should be "WHERE (SO_DTM=MAX_SO_DTM AND SO_DTM = MAX_SO_DTM)".

Comment: yes i guessed, so modified and tried with "WHERE ( SO_DTM=MAX_SO_DTM )" but ends with ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined" .The inner select works fine, facing issues only with outer select.

Comment: Is this nested in another query? Try to use qualified names "WHERE dt.SO_DTM = dt.MAX_SO_DTM"

Comment: i have edited the 2nd query which i have used after modifying. is there any other way to achieve the same? tried with many options but nothing clicked.

Comment: it's also one of the option i tried but my bad ended with : ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined".

Comment: But it should wotk when you alias, maybe you have to alias both columns,  QSRP_SO_DTM and SP_SO_DTM

Comment: @doenth If we Include TOP function will the Logical Sequence of Processing be :                                                                                                                           `                                                                                                   
FROM
WHERE
GROUP BY
HAVING
OLAP-function
QUALIFY -- Teradata specific
SAMPLE or EXPAND ON  -- both are Teradata specific
ORDER                                                                                                          TOP`

Comment: `top` is mutually exclusive with `sample/expand on`

Comment: If in Teradata we are only using either SAMPLE  or TOP  , with an ORDER BY  , the logical order  for TOP seems to take place after ORDER BY  as opposed to SAMPLE which occurs before ORDER BY.

Comment: @pchegoor: Correct, if it's combined with ORDER BY it's done *after* sorting.