# using WHERE clause in inline view/derived table

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have query, inspired from [qualify in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18820104/qualify-clause-in-oracle) to select unique active users from my table.
Query looks like this

```
SELECT
    COUNT(ID)
FROM
    (
        SELECT  MB.*
                ,ROW_NUMBER ()
                    OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY registered_date_time DESC)
                LATEST_DATE
        FROM TBL_ID MB
     ) A
WHERE 
    LATEST_DATE = 1
AND ID_STATUS = 'Active' 
AND UPPER(PROFILE_RULE) IN ('Allow 1','Allow 2')
```

Running this query I get a count. From the perspective of optimizing the query I tried moving the `WHERE` clause inside the inline view and query looks like this

```
SELECT
    COUNT(ID)
FROM
    (
        SELECT  MB.*
                ,ROW_NUMBER ()
                    OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY registered_date_time DESC)
                LATEST_DATE
        FROM TBL_ID MB
        WHERE
                ID_STATUS = 'Active' 
        AND UPPER(PROFILE_RULE) IN ('Allow 1','Allow 2')
     ) A
WHERE 
    LATEST_DATE = 1
```

But now I get a different count. I assume I am missing any detail or it's the expected behaviour? As per my understanding this should not affect the result dataset. Correct me if wrong.

Answer (score 3):

1st query: you're calculating `latest_date` for **all** records in the table. Then you're counting those whose `latest_date = 1` and satisfy other `where` conditions.

2nd query: you're taking rows that satisfy WHERE condition, and *calculate* `latest_date` out of that record pool. Then, in the main query, you're counting only rows whose `latest_date = 1`.

---

So, why do they differ? Because the 1st query's `latest_date` doesn't have to belong to *active* status or specified *profile rules*, but some other combination(s) of those values. It means that you've already ruled out certain rows from the result.

Comment: If the use case demands to count only those which fall in these WHERE filters, which query would get all records? I am confused making an intuition out of it

Comment: From my point of view, the 2nd query as its subquery works on records you're interested in.